# How to save name of select option instead of value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have this code:

```js
$("#subscription").on('change', function(){
  $('#plan').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="bank_name" class="form-control input-md chosen-select" id="subscription">
  <option value="">Choose Bank</option>
  <option value="swiftbank1">bank 1</option>
  <option value="swiftbank2">bank 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="plan" class="form-control input-md" name="swift">
```

What it does is add swift code in to the input field, that works fine!

Problem is that when I add data on database then both values is what I choose example I choose bank 1 then both will be saved as `swiftbank1` .

I need it to save bank name (`bank 1`) and swift (`swiftbank1`) in database.

I understand that value is what it is but is it possible to add name in database instead of value? In this case this value works to be passed from selection to input.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean with name for isntance bank 1 instead of swiftbank1?

Comment: any problem with this `<option value="bank1">bank 1</option>`?

Comment: it saves swiftbank1 in database for option but yes i need it to save bank 1 instead

Comment: @devpro then it will not pass swiftbank1 to input form

Comment: yes this will not pass this value

Comment: How are you generating these inputs, where does the information come from? You should only have to store 1 value in the database - the value - as the other can always be retrieved based on that value.

Comment: @jeroen information is simple text

Comment: It should be in the database, a configuration file or something similar.

Comment: I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript) might answer your question.

Comment: @IngusGraholskis check my solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.text` for getting selected text.

```js
$("#subscription").on('change', function(){
var text = $("#subscription :selected").text();
var value = $("#subscription").val();
console.log(text); // this will print text
console.log(value); // this will print value
//var plan = $('#plan').val(text); // this will change the value of plan
$("#plan").attr("value",text); // this will add the value attribute 
$('#plan').val(text); // this will change the value of plan
$('#subscription :selected').val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="bank_name" class="form-control input-md chosen-select" id="subscription">
<option value="">Choose Bank</option>
<option value="swiftbank1">bank 1</option>
<option value="swiftbank2">bank 2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="plan" class="form-control input-md" name="swift">
```

Comment: @IngusGraholskis: chk the snippet

Comment: this just copy bank name to SWIFT but at SWIFT need to be swiftbank1

Comment: it just copy bank name to input now instead of swift

Comment: @IngusGraholskis: than just use `value` instead of `text`

Comment: @IngusGraholskis: in `$("#plan").attr("value",value);` and `$('#plan').val(value);`

Comment: it does the same thing my code did only yours is bigger .still saves option as swiftbank1 instead of bank 1

Comment: @IngusGraholskis: in these two lines, u can get everything `console.log(text); // this will print text
console.log(value); // this will print value` u must need to learn this.

Comment: @IngusGraholskis: if i select `bank 1` than swift value should be `swiftbank1` and bank should be `bank 1` not `swiftbank1` .. right

Comment: yes that how it should look and be saved on database

Comment: there is one good and one bad thing :D they do save but NAME result saves in SWIFT place and SWIFT result saves in NAME place.also before saving both results showing as bank name not name and swift

Comment: also #subscription is the one  saves wrong reslult. it should save as bank name not the #plan

Comment: @IngusGraholskis: then change the value as u need.

Comment: @IngusGraholskis: finally, glad to help u

Answer (score 0):

try this to get text of selected option

```
$("#subscription").on('change', function(){
    $('#plan').val(this.options[this.selectedIndex].text);
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cjyzsxt6/ look at this fiddle. bank 1 is placed in the input box

Comment: Thats not what i need

Comment: hey wats the ouput you need from javascript. you need the value or text or both

Comment: when user select "bank 1" javascript pass value "swiftbank1" to the input. the problem is that on putting it in database option value in database is also "swiftbank1" instead of "bank 1"

Answer (score 0):

Since you will need to pass the value to store in database so a quick way is to keep the `value` as `swiftbank1###bank1`

Split the string with ### on server end and store them separately like this:

```
 $selectValue = $_POST['select_name'];
 $valueArray = explode("####",$selectValue);
```

`$valueArray[0]` will have `swiftbank1` and `$valueArray[1]` will have `bank1`

Comment: I do not get it till end were will i put $valueArray?

Comment: in your .php file where the form values are posted

Comment: and were then swiftbank1###bank1 will store?

Comment: no where, you just need to pass it to get concatenated value as post ... and then your new values will be accessed by `$valueArray[0]` and `$valueArray[1]`

Comment: i m sorry i m a newbe in arrays :D

Answer (score 0):

use this `$('#plan').val($('#subscription option:selected').text());`

Comment: it just copy bank name to input

Comment: no in input must be this swiftbank1 and need that bank name saves in option value

Comment: you mean you want the textbox to show the value of option but want to store the text in the DB. Is that so.. ?

Comment: Its fixed check for checked answer :)

Comment: Please, always give some explanation and not only the plain code